# Are there any issues to doing 2 rounds of AES-128? How is the security compared to AES-256?

Tags: aes, modes-of-operation, cryptographic-hardware

I have a SoC with hardware AES-128 encryption, which is obviously quite efficient in terms of power usage and memory used. However, we would like to have AES-256 encryption (half for commercial reasons, half for post-quantum security).
To achieve this, we consider:

- Using software encryption (which will be slower, use more power, and at the least require more code and hence flash space).
- Using 2 rounds of AES-128 one on the other, with different keys, effectively giving us a key length of 256 bits.

I am aware that 2 round of 128 bits is not the same as 1 round of 256 bits, but as I'm not an expert, I was wondering if anyone knows about drawbacks or vulnerability introduced by such practice, and ultimately if this would be equivalent to the security brought by AES-256 (ie, take a similar amount of time to break the encryption).

Also, I use AES CTR. The planned implementation would be create 1st cypher block, XOR it with 2nd, and XOR this with the plain text.

Comment: It suffers from a meet-in-the-middle attack. Read up on why we used 3DES instead of 2DES. Though if [Bernstein is right](https://cr.yp.to/hash/collisioncost-20090517.pdf) quantum computers might not speed meet-in-the-middle attacks, so you'd still get 128 bits of security against QCs (If he's wrong, you get 85 bits).

Comment: Xor in that case might be a safe combiner and not affected by meet in the middle.

Comment: @eckes: actually, xor would most certainly be subject to MitM attacks.  On the other hand, as any such attack would involve $2^{128}$ operations, it really is not of practical interest...

Comment: Hm, I said it is not vulnerable since it is a secure combiner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double encryption with 128-bit AES and two different keys does not give 256-bit security. In particular, a classic [Meet-in-the-Middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) applies, with expected cost $2^{128}$ encryptions and $2^{127}$ decryptions. As is, the attack requires ridiculously large amounts of memory, but improvements (using cycle finding with distinguished points) exist that greatly reduce memory requirement. See [section 5.3 on MitM](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/%7Epaulv/papers/JoC97.pdf#page=16) in Paul C. van Oorschot and Michael J. Wiener: *Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications* (in [Journal of Cryptology, January 1999, Volume 12, Issue 1](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00003816)).

I find it likely that a system has weaker points than AES-128's key size; systems may be vulnerable against key compromise or side-channel attacks for example.